# Elliptic curve cryptography in java

Tags: java

i want to implement ECC in java.whether jdk1.7 alone to implement it or need anyother open source like bouncy castle or JCE provider. if bouncy castle is used how to install the 
package for it.i dont know exact procedure. pls say the procedure to implement it.pls kindly clarify my doubt.

Comment: Java 1.1.7? Or Java 7? There is no Java 1.7.

Comment: Any relation to the `asp.net` tag? Nah, will remove it.

Answer (score 7):

But JDK 1.7 provides native

The Java SE 7 release adds the following features:

Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC)
A new native provider has been added to the Java SE 7 release that provides several ECC-based algorithms (ECDSA/ECDH). See Sun PKCS#11 Provider's Supported Algorithms in Java PKCS#11 Reference Guide for more information.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [Bouncy Castle - Using Elliptic Curves](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Using+Elliptic+Curve), there are some examples how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Even in Java 6, I couldn't get ECC to work through standard JCA APIs alone. I had to reference Sun's `sun.security.ec.NamedCurve` class to get the EC parameters initialized correctly, and I had to install the BouncyCastle as a provider as well.

From my experience, I don't think one can implement ECC code that is portable across security providers. While small, you'll have direct dependencies on BouncyCastle APIs.